# Можно ли так писать: "В произведении В.П. Астафьева... автор поднимает проблему..."?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> В произведении В.П. Астафьева, советского и российского писателя, автор поднимает проблему...

Учитель считает, что слово *автор* вовсе не нужно. Но в критических статьях есть такие выражения!

Answer (score 2):

Он мог даже иметь в виду: *нужно, чтобы его не было* (если не менять остального). При таком соотношении падежей имени написавшего и слова, которым на него ссылаются, может возникнуть вопрос: не является ли "автор" одним из персонажей произведения Астафьева? Уж больно активно (именительный падеж) и отвлечённо от собственного имени действует автор! Со словом "автор" более естественны варианты, где автор не доминирует над своим именем:

> Автор произведения [этого; одного из произведений сборника и т. п.],
>   советский и российский писатель Астафьев, поднимает проблему...

или:

> В произведении В. П. Астафьева, советского и российского писателя,
>   автором поднята проблема…

Comment: Вы так стараетесь сохранить "советского и российского", что портите всю идею редактирования. Здесь при таком построении должно быть в лучшем случае название произведения, а не причиндалы автора.

Comment: Это вопрос не редактирования с облагораживанием стиля, а исправления явных ошибок, так что я не покушаюсь на элементы исходного текста, которые этого не требуют (для кого-то это и вовсе полезное пояснение, что за писатель такой).

Comment: Вы относите стилистические ошибки к явным? Тогда, простите, вы вместо одной просто лепите другую, другого характера, но не менее явную. Короче, на мой взгляд, вы портите больше чем правите. И это вопрос именно редактирования. Грамматических ошибок в исходном тексте нет.

Comment: Без комментариев...

Answer (score 1):

Нет, так писать не стоит, но и просто сказать, что "автор" - лишнее, было бы неправильно. Тут другое.

Я думаю, что вы не совсем верно поняли учителя.
Конечно же, "автор" тут совсем не лишнее, это подлежащее, просто опустить которое, не перестроив фразу, здесь нет никакой возможности. . А вот что касается конструкции в которой без видимой необходимости дважды упоминается писатель/автор, то она вызывает ощущение избыточности, тавтологии, даже косноязычия.

Самый простой вариант правки:

***В произведении В. П. Астафьева, советского и российского писателя, поднимается проблема...***

Не могу сказать, что это изящный слог,  есть привкус казенщины, но все-таки много лучше стилистически. Дальнейшее улучшение - уже по желанию, в соответствии уже со стилем и направленностью вашего сочинения.

Comment: Получается, что это вовсе не грамматическая ошибка, а, боюсь ошибиться, плеоназм? Тогда какая ошибка? Моя другая учительница, профессор, говорит, что это встречается везде, в критических статьях это можно найти. Она статьи правила и была соавтором книги.

Comment: Встречается именно в таком виде? Эта стилистическая ошибка почти равносильна пренебрежительному "автор произведения Астафьева"; сильнее было бы разве что "муж жены Астафьева".

Comment: @ЮлияСмирнова **Плеоназм (если не нарочитый) и есть стилистическая ошибка**. Можно, правда, спорить, насколько уместно здесь именно слово "плеоназм", но стилистических огрех налицо.

Answer (score 1):

**В произведении В.П. Астафьева, советского и российского писателя, автор поднимает проблему...**

Можно ли так писать? Я считаю, что **так писать нельзя,** и хотелось бы увидеть ссылки на  "критические статьи, где есть такие выражения".

Я вижу здесь **грамматическую, а не стилистическую ошибку и могу предположить, что она заключается в следующем.** Если в предложении нужно обозначить принадлежность чего-либо лицу, то для этого надо использовать **притяжательные местоимения (свой, его),** а не форму Р.п. с указанием имени этого лица или другие варианты.

Например, нельзя сказать: **мама поставила цветы в комнате мамы или в маминой комнате**, но надо сказать: **мама поставила цветы в своей комнате.**

Поэтому автор (он же В.П. Астафьев) поднимет проблему **в своем произведении**, а не в произведении В.П. Астафьева.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант "без автора", возможно, об этом говорил учитель:

**В своем произведении В.П. Астафьев, советский и российский писатель, поднимает проблему...**

Сравнить:

(1) В сочинении Кати Ивановой она раскрывает тему...
(2) В своем сочинении Катя Иванова раскрывает тему....

Comment: А это уже какое-то какое-то изощренное стилистическое  издевательство. Упоминание о российском и советском писателе совершенно неуместно при таком построении фразы.

Comment: @Мимоходов, Согласен, и вот вариант правки: *(Известный) советский и российский писатель В.П. Астафьев в своем произведении "Кража" поднимает проблему...*

Comment: @М_Г  Править надо текст, цель которого вам известна. Насколько я понимаю, школьники пишут  сочинение "Проблема раскаяния (по тексту В.П. Астафьева), и речь идет о ПЕРВОМ  вступительном предложении. Ваш же вариант больше подходит для сочинения  "Какие проблемы ставит В.П. Астафьев в рассказе "Кража". Кроме того,  вопрос был  такой: "можно ли так писать", то есть надо провести анализ  предложенного  текста  (а не править его)  и  ЧЁТКО определить, есть ли в нем стилистические и грамматические ошибки и в чем они заключаются.

Comment: @М_Г  Наберите в поисковике исходную фразу, и вы увидите все варианты вступительных предложений по этому заданию. Они похожи по содержанию,  у них несовершенный стиль, но грамматических ошибок  в них вроде бы  нет. А вот для приведенного предложения вопрос остается открытым, и хотелось бы услышать ваше  обоснованное мнение, а также мнения других участников.